# Using LinkedHashMap.containsKey() gives strange outcome

Tags: java

I am kind of new to programming in Java, but am currently working on a simulator for some production process. In doing so, I found something very strange which I cannot seem to figure out and cannot find on the internet or in any other question on here.

As part of a production factory, I need a certain component to figure out if it can send items to any of its machines based on a recipe for the item. To do so, I found that using a LinkedHashMap is a nice implementation for such problems. This next piece of code describes the setup of the machines and creates the initial HashMap. It uses a list of machine configurations that each have a list of recipes that they are compatible with. The HashMap will be of the form `<Recipe, List<Machine>>` so that I can find available machines by searching for the recipes of the items that arrive.

```
public void setupMachines(List<Config> configurationList) {
    for (int i = 0; i<configurationList.size(); i++) {
        Config config = configurationList.get(i);
        Machine machine = new Machine(config, config.getName());

        for (int j = 0; j<config.getCompatibleRecipes().size(); j++){
            Recipe key = config.getCompatibleRecipes().get(j);
            if (!recipeInfo.containsKey(key)) {
                recipeInfo.put(key, new ArrayList<Machine>());
            }
            recipeInfo.get(key).add();
        }
    }
}
```

In the class of the group of machines the following piece of code is used to find a suitable machine for an item based on the recipe it got from the simulator, and sends that item from a queue to that machine.

```
public void checkAvailableMachinesAndRedirectItems() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i<queue.size()) {
        Lot lot = queue.get(i);
        Recipe key = lot.getRecipe();

        if (recipeInfo.containsKey(key)) { 
            if (!recipeInfo.get(key).isEmpty()) {
                Machine machine = recipeInfo.get(key).get(0);
                lot.setReservedMachine(machine);
                removeFromRecipeInfo(machine);
                queue.remove(lot);
                machine.take(lot);
            }
            else { i++; }
        }
        else { i++; }
    }
}
```

In a test file of the simulator I have to following piece of code to build two simple recipes and the group of machines that are needed to run the simulation.

```
MachineGroup machineGroup = new MachineGroup();
ArrayList<Config> configurationList = new ArrayList<Config>();    

//create two recipes:
Recipe recipeA = model.getSimFactory().createRecipe("RecipeA");
Recipe recipeB = model.getSimFactory().createRecipe("RecipeB");

//both recipes need to have the process step of passing through a machine
recipeA.add( new ProcessStep("MachineStep", machineGroup, ...with a bunch of variables... ) );
recipeB.add( new ProcessStep("MachineStep", machineGroup, ...with a bunch of variables... ) );

//Create two machine configurations:
Config configA = new Config(...bunch of variables...);
Config configB = new Config(...bunch of variables...);

//For this example both configs have just one compatible recipe:
configA.addCompatibleRecipe(recipeA);
configB.addCompatibleRecipe(recipeB);

//add both configs tho a list:
configurationList.add(configA);
configurationList.add(configB);

// -- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT STATEMENT -- \\
machineGroup.setupMachines(configurationList);
// *** ------- **** \\

//create a sink for deleted items that are completed:
model.getSimFactory().createProcessStepAndAddToRecipe("sinkStep", sink, recipeA);
model.getSimFactory().createProcessStepAndAddToRecipe("sinkStep", sink, recipeB);

//create a source for items with different recipes and inter arrival times:
Source sourceA = model.getSimFactory().createSource("SourceA", recipeA, 10L);
Source sourceB = model.getSimFactory().createSource("SourceB", recipeB, 8L);

engine.init(model);
model.addComponent(machineGroup);
engine.runSimulation(50L);
```

Which initializes a simulation (this stuff was already working properly) and using the `machineGroup.setupMachines()` function to create the factory setup with initial HashMap to look something like this: `{RecipeA=[MachineConfigA], RecipeB=[MachineConfigB]}`. However, the first IF-statement in the second piece of code (asking if the recipeInfo contains the recipe belonging to the lot) **never** returns true, even thought the HashCodes for the recipe of the lot and the recipe that is currently acting as a key value in the HashMap are identical.

Now for some reason unknown to myself I also tried this with the `machineGroup.setupMachines()` function just above the `engine.runSimulation()` function, and the strange thing is that the IF-statement now seems to work fine. I first thought this had something to do with adding some steps to the recipes after building the initial HashMap (source and sink), but from browsing the internet I mostly came to the conclusion that even thought the Object itself might have changed, the key value in the HashMap is only a pointer which is still pointing at the Object right? Again they have identical HashCodes.

My superior could also not figure out this behavior, but since he uses the LinkedHashMap a lot he and I would really like some more info on this topic. Does anybody know what is going on here?

I would like to repeat that I am not a javaguru yet, so simplifications and examples in your answers is much appreciated :).

Comment: If you’re seeing unreliable behavior with HashMap keys, my first guess is that the Recipe.hashCode() method is computing its returned value based on mutable state.  Changing a key object’s hashCode after it’s been added to a HashMap will break the HashMap’s functionality.  Edit your question and include the code of the Recipe class for a more conclusive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this problem is related to the object you store in the Key of the HashMap. Either the class does not override `hashCode()` or/and it does not override `equals()`.

You should verify that the objects stored and tested are equal.

The inner comparison code may help you to understand why. (simplified Java source of `HashMap.getNode()`)

> ```
>             do {
>                 if (e.hash == hash &&
>                     ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
>                     return e;
>             } while ((e = e.next) != null);
> ```